# Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018 Update) makes impossible to remove language

Tags: windows-10, powershell, language, input-languages

After updating latest release I got stuck with English(US) and English(UK) and non of them can be removed. The Remove button is greyed out.
Language packs cannot be uninstalled. Changing default input and display language doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well It's a duplicate of a question that is locked and I can't answer. Hope   I wont be punished for this duplicate, but this is really annoying  and lost few days searching for help. Hope it will help someone else.

Comment: If it is protected, and this is indeed a duplicate (I don't know the other question) you should have enough reputation now to post your answer there now. If it was closed for some other reason, hopefully yours won't get closed as a duplicate. Cheers!